# How do I add an MVC filter programmatically to select routes?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-routing

In ASP.Net Core I know how to add the `AuthorizeFilter` to all routes programmatically, like this..

```
services.AddMvc(options =>
{
    options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder().RequireAuthenticatedUser().Build()));
})
```

However, I would like to only select certain paths to do this to.  How can I do this?  I just need a way to enforce authentication at startup to select paths, without having to decorate every route manually with the attribute.  Thank you.

Comment: This may be a good candidate for Conventions https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/application-model#conventions

Comment: You could set the AuthorizeFilter on an area for example, or in a `BaseController` herited by the concerned controller no ?